# how to call popup when i click in table cell in ios objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview

```
self.infoView.hidden = NO;

self.infoView.backgroundColor = [[UIColor blackColor] colorWithAlphaComponent:0.7];
```

i want to call thin in table view

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    if (indexPath.row==0) {
        return;
    }

    NSMutableDictionary *Tag_Dic = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
    [Tag_Dic setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:indexPath.row] forKey:@"Tags"];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"MoveToNext" object:self userInfo:Tag_Dic];
    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    [defaults setInteger:indexPath.row forKey:@"SenderTag"];
    [defaults synchronize];
}
```

Comment: do you want to show UIAlertView on cell click ?

Answer (score 1):

Try this. You have to show `alertController` when tapped on `UITableViewCell`

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{


     [cell.button addTarget:self action:@selector(presentAlert) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
}
```

Then write your code for `UIAlertController` in `presentAlert` selector.

```
 UIAlertController * alert=   [UIAlertController

                              alertControllerWithTitle:@"Title"

                              message:@"message"

                              preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];



UIAlertAction* ok = [UIAlertAction

                     actionWithTitle:@"OK"

                     style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault

                     handler:^(UIAlertAction * action)

                     {

                     }];

UIAlertAction* cancel = [UIAlertAction

                         actionWithTitle:@"Cancel"

                         style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault

                         handler:^(UIAlertAction * action)

                         {

                             [alert dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];

                         }];



[alert addAction:ok];

[alert addAction:cancel];



[self presentViewController:alert animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to show alert when tableview cell is clicked then do following in `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` method.

For iOS 9 and earlier,

```
UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Title" message:@"Message" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" otherButtonTitles:@"Button1",@"Button2", nil];
alertView.delegate = self;
[alertView show];
```

and user `UIAlertView`'s delegate method to implement your logic when button is clicked

`- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex`

For iOS 9 and onwards (`UIAlertView` is deprecated.)

```
UIAlertAction *actionOK = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"OK" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:^(UIAlertAction * _Nonnull action) {

    //handel when OK button is pressed.

}];

UIAlertAction *actionCancel = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"Cancel" style:UIAlertActionStyleCancel handler:^(UIAlertAction * _Nonnull action) {

    //handel when Cancel button is pressed.

}];

UIAlertController *alertVC = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:@"Title" message:@"Message" preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];

[alertVC addAction:actionOK];
[alertVC addAction:actionCancel];

[self presentViewController:alertVC animated:true completion:nil];
```

Answer (score 0):

In ios 8.3 and earlier work this code,

```
- (void)saveButton {
     UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Title" message:@"Message" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alert show];
}
```

After 8.4 popup action used UIAlertController and i have create the UITextField in popup view and action is give below,

```
- (void)callAlert {
    UIAlertController *alert= [UIAlertController
                                  alertControllerWithTitle:@"Enter Folder Name"
                                  message:@"Keep it short and sweet"
                                  preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];

    UIAlertAction* ok = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"OK" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault
                                               handler:^(UIAlertAction * action){
                                                   //Do Some action here
                                                   UITextField *textField = alert.textFields[0];
                                                   NSLog(@"text was %@", textField.text);

                                               }];
    UIAlertAction* cancel = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"Cancel" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault
                                                   handler:^(UIAlertAction * action) {

                                                       NSLog(@"cancel btn");

                                                       [alert dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];

                                                   }];

    [alert addAction:ok];
    [alert addAction:cancel];

    [alert addTextFieldWithConfigurationHandler:^(UITextField *textField) {
        textField.placeholder = @"folder name";
        textField.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeDefault;
    }];

    [self presentViewController:alert animated:YES completion:nil];

}
```

Finally call this method where you want, hope its helpful.